# Fill Spinner with Room Database

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-room

I am making my first app. (with lots of google and tutorials).

I made a Room Database with the following table.

[image]

Now I want to fill a Spinner with the Strings of the column "team_name".

On Spinner Selection the "team_url" should be put in a variable.

Cant find out how.

Thanks for helping.

Greetings!

Update:

```
    Spinner league = findViewById(R.id.league);
    tableDAO = TeamDatabase.getInstance(this).getTableDAO();

    List<Team> allTable = tableDAO.getTable();

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new ArrayList<String>());
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    league.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

    spinnerAdapter.addAll(allTable);
    spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: are u using kotlin or java?

Comment: Hello, i am using java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using Java and have some code similar to this to initialize the `Spinner`.

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new ArrayList<>());  
spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

what you need to do is fetch the data from DB using Room and add them to the adapter

```
spinnerAdapter.addAll(yourList);
spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and once the user clicks any items, you can use the callback function to get the team name and use Room to fetch the corresponding team_url.

The Dao of your Room may look like this

```
@Dao
public interface TeamDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM team")
    List<Team> getAll();

    @Query("SELECT team_name FROM team")
    List<String> getAllTeamName();

    @Query("SELECT team_url FROM team WHERE team_name = :name")
    public abstract List<String> findURLByName(String name);
```

}

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping.
I updated the main post with the code i tried.
But it doesnt work.

Comment: with "spinnerAdapter.addAll(String.valueOf(allTable));"
the spinneradapter is only filled with 1 object

Comment: 1. the adapter is accepting String as the element inside, so that's why you cannot resolve the addAll line.

Comment: 2. If you do `String.valueOf(allTable)` it will convert the list into one String(definitely is not what you want), you should either return a List of String and then call `addAll` or you should loop through the list of Team object and can `add` one at a time

Comment: Why not just get the ArrayList first and then pass it in the Adapter's constructor? Is it necessary/better to do it via `notifyDataSetChanged`?